# Firebase Issue - "user Does not exists in database" when logging in to android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I create a new user on android app, the credentials are registered to firebase, however when I log in with those credentials my dialog box appears stating 'User Does Not Exists" even though user is registered in firebase database.

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtPhone, edtPassword;
    Button btnSignin;

    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        edtPassword = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        edtPhone = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
        btnSignin = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

        //Init Firebase
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference();

        btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                mDialog.show();

                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //Check if User doesnt Exist in Database
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                            //Get User Information
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                            if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign In Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign In Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User Does Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The user exists in the database, and when i log in with these credentials I am not able to sign in.

[image]

Comment: No, the user exists only as your data. You need to use `FirebaseAuth` to sign in users.

Comment: No I dont want to user FireBaseAuth to sign in users. its fine the way it is, as it was working earlier

Comment: Then it's a matter of your own logic.

Comment: Lol. Use a debugger. Way easier than expecting anyone else to solve your problems

Comment: Speaking of logic, you can save a line by calling `mDialog.dismiss()` outside the `if`

Comment: There is an issue with my configuration however I do not know how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()` is being evaluated as false.

Because you are trying to evaluate the root of the project:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference();
```

to a branch inside the `User` branch:

```
dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString())
```

You need to fetch a specific branch:

```
database.getReference("if_there_are_another_branches_they_go_here/User")
```

in order for `dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString())` to work as you expect